# How to convert string to php from the following format?

Tags: php, date, timestamp, date-conversion

I am trying to convert a string to date in the following format using PHP. It is a timestamp, but I am not sure of the technical term for its format so I am having some trouble converting it.

```
$timestamp = "20150611183741.941Z";
```

How can I convert this into a data type?

Comment: I get that it's 2015-06-11 18:37:41, but what is 941Z?

Comment: @BrianCohan: Probably microseconds and Zulu time.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Answer (score 5):

The `.941Z` is milliseconds and an identifier indicating this is in UTC. Using [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) you can parse that string to get the date format you are looking for

```
$timestamp = "20150611183741.941Z";
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('YmdHis.ue', $timestamp);

echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/389957)

Comment: Hey man, thanks a lot. That really helped. Right now, in PHP, I am trying to get this same current date and time format from a linux server. I wonder if there is a way that will allow me to retrieve the date back as  in that format. for example,      $currentTime = time(); so that $currentTime will be something like "20150701183741.018Z"??

Comment: You can use DateTime for this as well. Just look at the DateTime::format options which will look a lot like `YmdHis.ue` just DateTime::createFromFormat() used.

Answer (score 0):

I know its an old thread and you probably found your answer by now, just updating it with what worked for me. u is for microseconds, what I needed was v for milliseconds v was added in PHP 7 FYI.

```
$datetime = new DateTime('2018-01-22T18:33:05.230234');

echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.v\Z'); // output 2018-01-22T18:33:05.230Z
```

You could also achieve the above in PHP < 7 with the following code.

```
echo sprintf(
    "%s%03dZ",
    $datetime->format("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\."),
    floor($datetime->format("u") / 1000)
); // output 2018-01-22T18:33:05.230Z
```